# Angular Cannot read property 'subscribe' of null

Tags: angular, observable

I am getting the error

> cannot read property 'subscribe' of null.

This is where the error is happening, this is called by the constructor of its class:

```
loadItems() {
    this.itemService.subscribeItems().subscribe(x => {
      this.items = x;
      console.log(x);
    });
}
```

It calls this services method, this is where the issue is I think. It may be to do with the `return null`

```
subscribeItems(): Observable<Item[]> {
    this.session.uid.subscribe(x => {
            return this.af.database.list('users/' + x + '/Items')
            .map(Item.fromJsonList);
    });
    return null;
}
```

the session service holds the uid which is updated when the user logs in:
This part works ok.

```
_uid = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
uid = this._uid.asObservable();
```

Comment: Try to remove `return null;`

Comment: I had tried. I tried creating a local var of observable of the type and returning at the end. Instead of the inside return I just assigned to that var. Still no good however

Comment: If it helps anyone, I got this error on 'key up' in a text input when I forgot to wrap Validators in `Validators.compose([...])` in a `FormGroup` declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
subscribeItems(): Observable<Item[]> {
    return this.session.uid.subscribe(x => {
            return this.af.database.list('users/' + x + '/Items')
            .map(Item.fromJsonList => Item.fromJsonList.json());
    });
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Type subscription is not assignable to type Observable<Item[]>

Comment: What you get back  does not match the condition Observable<Item[]> try removing this see what the console log shows

Comment: The this.session.uid.subscribe returns a string. This is used to get the uid for querying the database inside. When the user logs in the this uid changes and will trigger the inside to run again using the x variable to return the correct items for that user.

Comment: Your question  has been answered you now get something  back, why is not assignable to Observable<Item[]> is a new question  that needs more detail because  most probably you omitted something in your code like .json() on your map

Answer (score 0):

this error is happening because an observable/a service function is null or returning null.

so whichever it is initialize it first.

eg

```
Items():Observable<any>
{ 
   let itemToReturn = new Observable();

   if(this.itemService.subscribeItems()){
       this.itemService.subscribeItems().subscribe(data => itemToReturn.next(data)); 
   }
   return itemToReturn; 
}
```

Calling this method or subscribing to it won't error since it always returns an initialized item.